# Split String using delimiter in Java

Tags: java, string

I need help in splitting two email address which are seperated by a Delimiter 'AND'. I have issue when splitting, when the email address has got the characters'AND' in the email id. For eg, if the email address that needs to be split is something like the below. There are no whitespaces between the two email address.

```
'anandc@AND.comANDxyz@yahoo.co.in', and the delimiter is'AND'
```

In the above case, there seems to be three items extracted instead of two. Can someone please help me solve this. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Use `" AND "` as the separator (i.e. include the spaces) and you should be fine.

Comment: is the delimiter always AND? does it always have 1 white space surrounding the delimiter?

Comment: Thanks for the Instant response. Actually there are some emails, where there is no space in between two emailids. Only the 'AND' operator is present.So the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response hovanessyan. There is no whitespace. Its always AND

Comment: if your email addresses are always consists AND with surrounded white spaces so it is very better to use " AND " including both sides white spaces

Answer (score 2):

You can use `" AND "` as delimiter.

```
 String str="anandc@AND.com AND xyz@yahoo.co.in";
 String[] emailArr=str.split(" AND ");
```

Or you can use following `regex`

```
  String str = "anandc@AND.com AND xyz@yahoo.co.in";
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+
                                   (\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})");
  Matcher matcher = p.matcher(str);
  while (matcher.find()) {
     System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
  }
```

Out put

```
 anandc@AND.com
 xyz@yahoo.co.in
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But as specified earlier, there are no whitespaces in the delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

Giving correct output

```
public class Test {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            String text = "anandc@AND.com AND xyz@yahoo.co.in ";
            String[] splits = text.split(" AND ");
            for (int i = 0; i < splits.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("data :" + splits[i]);
            }
        }

    }
```

Output is

```
data :anandc@AND.com    
data :xyz@yahoo.co.in
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

`String[] splits = text.split("\\s+AND\\s+");`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried this, but it doesnt seem to work

Comment: I have written code assuming your string is enclosed in single quotes. If not, remove the substring part and try it out. I have edited the post. Check it out.

Comment: As I specified there is no whitespaces between the delimiter and the email address.I tried without the substring as well. But doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)
the regular expression will be case sensitive

actually, the best is to use delimiters exression that you are sure will not be in the adress